# Leaflet legend appears before the overlay feature is selected

Tags: leaflet

I have two overlay features in a leaflet map. When I load the webpage, I only have one overlay set to load, however both legends appear. Is there a way to make my second legend (for the overlay that isn't selected yet to appear once its selected? I attached my legend code below, but I cannot attach the rest of the code for organization privacy reasons.

```
    legend.addTo(map);

    // This is for myMajorCities legend           
    map.on('overlayadd', function(eventLayer){
        if (eventLayer.name === 'Major Cities Population'){
          myMajorCities.addTo(map);
        } 
    });

    map.on('overlayremove', function(eventLayer){
        if (eventLayer.name === 'Major Cities Population'){
             map.removeControl(myLegend);
        } 
    }); 

    var myLegend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

    myLegend.onAdd = function (map) {

        var myDiv = L.DomUtil.create('myDiv', 'info myLegend'),
            grades = [0, 1000000, 1500000, 2000000, 2500000, 5000000],
            labels = [];

        // loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each 
   interval
        for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            myDiv.innerHTML +=
                '<i style="background:' + getMyColor(grades[i] + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                grades[i] + (grades[i + 1] ? '&ndash;' + grades[i + 1] + '<br>' : '+');
        }

        return myDiv;
    };

    myLegend.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add both legends to the map, when you don't want to show both. Also you add the wrong element to the map in `overlayadd`

```
  legend.addTo(map);

    // This is for myMajorCities legend           
    map.on('overlayadd', function(eventLayer){
        if (eventLayer.name === 'Major Cities Population'){
          map.addControl(myLegend);
        } 
    });

    map.on('overlayremove', function(eventLayer){
        if (eventLayer.name === 'Major Cities Population'){
             map.removeControl(myLegend);
        } 
    }); 

    var myLegend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

    myLegend.onAdd = function (map) {

        var myDiv = L.DomUtil.create('myDiv', 'info myLegend'),
            grades = [0, 1000000, 1500000, 2000000, 2500000, 5000000],
            labels = [];

        // loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each 
   interval
        for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            myDiv.innerHTML +=
                '<i style="background:' + getMyColor(grades[i] + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                grades[i] + (grades[i + 1] ? '&ndash;' + grades[i + 1] + '<br>' : '+');
        }

        return myDiv;
    };

   // Remove this
  //  myLegend.addTo(map);
```

Comment: I want to show both legends, but at different times when different overlays are clicked. What do you mean I added the wrong element in overlayadd? I apologize I am extremely new to JavaScript (and coding in general).